# Non void function does not return any value

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve the basic twosum problem on leetcode using brute force i.e. two nested for loops. We are given an array and we have to find a single pair of two numbers whose sum is a specific given value. I've checked the code thrice. The code seems right to me. I don't know why it's not returning any value.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class Solution 
{
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) 
    {
        vector<int>::iterator it, it2;
        vector<int> sol;
        
        for(it = nums.begin(); it != nums.end(); it++)
            {    
            for(it2 = it+1; it2 != nums.end(); it2++)
                {
                    if((*it) + (*it2) == target)
                    {
                        sol.push_back(*it);
                        sol.push_back(*it2);
                        return sol;
                    }    
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the `if` condition may not be satisfied for certain input in which case the control flow will not encounter any `return` statement and will have **undefined behavior**.

You can solve it by adding a `return` statement at that point of your function body where no conditions are satisfied so that even if no condition is satisfied, the control flow will pass through that `return` statement. For example, you can add a `return` as shown below:

```
vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) 
{
    vector<int>::iterator it, it2;
    vector<int> sol;
    
    for(it = nums.begin(); it != nums.end(); it++)
    {    
        for(it2 = it+1; it2 != nums.end(); it2++)
        {
            if((*it) + (*it2) == target)
            {
                sol.push_back(*it);
                sol.push_back(*it2);
                return sol;
            }    
        }
    }
    return sol; //added this return 
}
```

Comment: I suspect that you might want to _move_ instead of _copy_ the return statement. It currently returns only a single pair at most.

Comment: @MSalters Yeah but the point of my answer is to solve the current problem faced by the OP by adding a `return` at correct point.Also, the OP seems to be new(a beginner) to C++, so i wouldn't recommend `std::move()` unless specifically asked .

Comment: @AnoopRana: I didn't mean `std::move` - I meant moving the return statement from inside the loop to the end of the function. You currently have two return statements, you copied the one inside the loop to the end.

Comment: @MSalters Okay. Yes moving the return statement makes more sense than copying it for the reason you mentioned. But the OP should take care of that. The main point of the answer is that "many times we(programmers) encounter such functions which have many `if` , `else` blocks which have `return` statements inside of them. And in those case it is important to consider the scenario of what happens if none of the conditions are satisfied. And so add the `return` accordingly."

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) 
{
    vector<int>::iterator it, it2;
    vector<int> sol;
    
    for(it = nums.begin(); it != nums.end(); it++)
    {    
        for(it2 = it+1; it2 != nums.end(); it2++)
        {
                if((*it) + (*it2) == target)
                {
                    sol.push_back(*it);
                    sol.push_back(*it2);
                    return sol;
                }    
            }
        }
}
```

The problem is if `if((*it) + (*it2) == target)` is fasle in your entire program, you function will not return anything, hence the error.

If leetcode ensure you that there will be at least one time that `if((*it) + (*it2) == target)` is `true`, you can fill in with some placeholder values so that it wiil return on any path, like:

```
vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) 
{
    vector<int>::iterator it, it2;
    vector<int> sol;
    
    for(it = nums.begin(); it != nums.end(); it++)
    {    
        for(it2 = it+1; it2 != nums.end(); it2++)
        {
                if((*it) + (*it2) == target)
                {
                    sol.push_back(*it);
                    sol.push_back(*it2);
                    return sol;
                }    
            }
        }
    return std::vector<int>{-1};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if ((*it) + (*it2) == target) is false you don’t return anything so you must add a return statement at the end of the function.

```
vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) 
{
    vector<int>::iterator it, it2;
    vector<int> sol;
    
    for(it = nums.begin(); it != nums.end(); it++)
    {    
        for(it2 = it+1; it2 != nums.end(); it2++)
        {
                if((*it) + (*it2) == target)
                {
                    sol.push_back(*it);
                    sol.push_back(*it2);
                    return sol;
                }    
            }
        }
    return std::vector<int>{-1};
}
```

Also, I’m not sure if I am talking about the same problem but I believe you are supposed to return an array of the indices and not the actual values.

Example:
[2, 7, 3]
target: 9
Don’t return [2, 7]
Instead
[0, 1]

Comment: Empty vector for no results seems more appropriate that invalid index.